# Openfire with SPARK xmpp where to code for the reject event

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have a openfire server where agents chat from SPARK XMPP client, I would like a bit of help. I want to know how the SPARK client accept/reject event can be intercepted and we can write some code for it

If, I am not clear do hit me up with comments, I would be glad to answer

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Spark it's a world and, of course, what Prune said. I've looked for documentation for you: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/sparkplug-kit.jsp . If you want to compile a your version of Spark, of course igniterealtime's forum it's a good place if you'll not find any tutorial